# android.support.v4 causing force close on some devices

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, proguard

I have one application listed in playstore, for which some user have reported force close issue. I went to developer console to see the details and that showed the following message. I have used `android support library` in the application. The class extends `FragmentActivity` and the other imports i have used are

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
```

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.support.v4.a.h.done(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at my.package.name.k.n(Unknown Source)
at my.package.name.k.d(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.a.a.e(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.a.g.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
... 4 more

For applications that include obfuscated code, stack traces contain obfuscated symbol  
names. If the application was obfuscated using ProGuard, you can unobfuscate the stack 
trace using the "retrace" tool, included in the Android SDK Tools r8 and later. For 
more information, see the ProGuard document.
```

Comment: This looks like a NullPointerException in *your* code (at my.package...). We need more code.

Comment: If you can get an unobfuscated log, that would also help.